# Unity 3d clear other LineRendrer's when using one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

hello i'm new to unity 3d.

so what i want is to Draw a LineRendrer but i when a draw it, i want to clear the other LineRendrer.

see the 2 images for a demo:

[image]

here is the code that i use to draw the line and were i want to clear the other Lines.

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineAnimatoor : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] private float animationDuration = 5f;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private Vector3[] linePoints;
    private int pointsCount;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();

        // store the points
        pointsCount = lineRenderer.positionCount;
        linePoints = new Vector3[pointsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++){
            linePoints[i] = lineRenderer.GetPosition(i);
        }

        StartCoroutine (AnimateLine());

    }

    private IEnumerator AnimateLine(){

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount-1; i++){

            float startTime = Time.time;
            Vector3 startPosition = linePoints[i];
            Vector3 endtPosition = linePoints[i+1];
            Vector3 pos = startPosition;

            while(pos !=endtPosition){

                float t = (Time.time - startTime)/ animationDuration;
                pos = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endtPosition, t);

                for (int j = i+1; j < pointsCount; j++){
                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(j, pos);
                }
                yield return null;
                
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two options, depending on how you line renderers are creatied which is not mentioned in the quiestion.

1.- If each of your line renderers is a component of spare gameObjects, you need to hold a reference to those in a higher order class to eliminate/destroy the line renderer of your interest. For example a `List<LineRenderer>` in a `class LineRendererManager` where you handle the lifecycle of your lines.

2.- Another chance is to have only one line renderer so that when you reset the points of it, the previous one will disseapear along with the points re-setting.
This would involve calling the line initialization of your line renderer to store the points, more concretely :

```
// store the points
pointsCount = lineRenderer.positionCount;
linePoints = new Vector3[pointsCount];
for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++){
    linePoints[i] = lineRenderer.GetPosition(i);
}
```

from somewhere else in the code instead of the `Start`. It would be called from a button click event or from whatever triggers your second line generation instead from the `Start`. That way you would have your lineRenderer active, able to set the ne line´s point when needed.

For more detailed answer you would need to specify how the line is generated, but if you only want one active line and need to get rid of the previous one when created, your option would be option 2.

Comment: TY ery much..bcs i'm new to unitiy i didn't know how to resolve this but now i know that i need to create a class managing those lines....i did it and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

To clear the LineRenderer you just need to set positionCount to 0:

`LineRenderer.positionCount = 0;`